# How to call an edge of a cycle in a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

An edge of a graph is said to be a bridge if its removal increases the number of components in the examined graph. What is the term for an edge which is NOT a bridge of the investigated graph? Is it a cyclic edge or something else?

Comment: I'd just call it an inner edge of the component